# add root url to href in jQuery

Tags: jquery

how can i add the root url to the href?

```
jQuery('#breadcrumb li').prepend('<li><a href="root url here">Home</a> > </li>');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery('#breadcrumb li').prepend('<li><a href="/">Home</a> > </li>');
```

A slash will always point to the web root.

Comment: "root url" is not really a specific term, I think. If user472285 is thinking of a website under one domain, then yes. If he's working in a subdirectory, that's not what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rooturl = http://example.com/;

jQuery('#breadcrumb li').prepend('<li><a href="' + rooturl + '">Home</a> > </li>');
```